# i install my pc ubuntu 22.04 and sudo apt update isnot properly done

Tags: apt, updates, sudo, repository, software-sources

```
Err:1 http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt jammy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrors.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt jammy-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrors.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt jammy-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrors.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt jammy-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrors.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrors.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrors.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrors.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrors.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
spiro@spiro
```